# How to run a ~/.bashrc function as a GUI login item

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

I am using Debian Stretch with Xfce. My `~/bin` directory has a lot of scripts. This of course is in my `$PATH`, and I run scripts from there sometimes when I log in to Xfce via Session and Startup > Application Autostart. In my `~/.bashrc` file I have my custom aliases and functions. I use the functions in the `~/.bashrc` file for shorter bits of code that I would rather not create a whole script for in `~/bin`. However, sometimes I would like to run a function from my `~/.bashrc` file as a GUI login item.

I created a test function in `~/.bashrc`. I then set that function to run from `~/.profile`. The function runs successfully when I do the following:
- Run `bash -l` from a terminal
- Log in on tty session

However it does not run when I log in to my graphical Xfce environment from LightDM. The function does not run either when added in Session and Startup > Application Autostart in Xfce. To test further I added a command directly in `~/.profile`. It does run when I log in to Xfce.

I am unable to run a `~/.bashrc` function when logging into a graphical environment. Is this bug? Should a setting be enabled to run functions at GUI login? Or, is my system just designed this way? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "login item"? Do you just want to have the functions available in a login shell when you want them? Or do you want one of these functions to be run automatically when you log in?

Comment: I want it to run once when I log in. I could run it in my `~/.bashrc`, but this runs it every time I open a terminal session.

Comment: So you just want one specific function to i) run once each time you log in and ii) be available to run on demand in normal (non-login) shells? Why don't you just call the function from `~/.profile` then?

Comment: I had tried to call it from `~/.profile`, and it did not run for some reason.

Comment: OK. Please **[edit]** your question and give us more details then. First, explain exactly what you want to happen (I'm afraid "I want to run it as a login item" isn't very understandable). Then, explain that you put it in `~/.profile` and it failed. Also mention whether you need this to happen when you log in from the GUI or from the command line or both. Finally, explain why you don't just put that one function into a script and have the script run on login.

Comment: @terdon (I think I would have been more clear if I had not posted yesterday when I was overly tired.) I think I have gotten to the bottom of my issue on trying to call a `~/.bashrc` function from `~/.profile` when logging in to an x session (Xfce). I will plan update my question and all the information by later on this week. Thanks

Comment: @terdon I finally was able to update those details for my question.

Comment: What do you see in `.xsession-errors`?

Comment: @tripleee I checked it and found this. `(xfce4-session:10414): xfce4-session-WARNING **: Unable to launch "function_login_test" (specified by autostart/test.desktop): Failed to execute child process "function_login_test" (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Adding the actual code you are attempting to run to your question would clarify it immensely. Please [edit] it to update with more details.

Answer (score 3):

The default `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` only if `BASH_VERSION` is non-empty, i.e. (from default `.profile`):

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Under Lightdm, startup scripts are executed by `/bin/sh`, which on Debian is a symlink to [`/bin/dash`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_Almquist_shell). This means that when `~/.profile` is sourced at startup, `BASH_VERSION` is empty, and thus, `~/.bashrc` does not get sourced.

**Possible solutions**

1. Run the functions from `~/bin`
2. Another solution (if you need more than one at startup) is to have a 
   separate file, say `~/.startup_functions` 
   where you keep all your functions, source the file from `.profile` and 
   execute the functions from here. Notice that, since you are executing 
   them with `/bin/dash`, you have to check for compatibility.

Otherwise, if you want to use `bash` as startup shell and source
`.bashrc` at startup, one thing you can do is to set `bash` as
default `/bin/sh`, i.e. run

```
$ dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

and follow the instructions.

If you want to define the functions in `.bashrc` and run them at startup, notice that `.profile` loads `.bashrc` only if the shell is interactive, if (as by default) you have the following test in `.bashrc`

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
    *) return;;
esac
```

which means you would have to either remove this test or define the functions you need before, anyway, I'd stick to running the function from `~/bin`.

Comment: I could not quite get the `~/.bash_profile` option or removing the `$BASH_VERSION` test to work in `~/.profile` for the login `~/.bashrc` function. Thank you though for the input. I'll plan on just using `~/bin` then. That'll do just fine... ;)

Comment: @jbrock my fault, this wouldn't even work. I played around a bit with it this weekend, and edited the answer to include more accurate info. But yes, your best option is to use `~/bin` in my opinion.

Comment: I tried every new step that you added. No luck. Commenting out that `case` statement actually made it where I could not log in on GUI at all. (I of course un-commented it in a tty.) I appreciate the steadfast and valiant effort though. I did learn a few things. No issue in running my functions from `bin`.